# How to use shared preference on tap in flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I would like to save the id on tap the item for that I am using shared preference but unable to use the same id in entire application.

```
  onTap: ()async{
               var orderId = orderitems['order_id'];
               print("my_orders_order_id :: "+orderId);
               _loaded_my_orders_order_id = await _setOrderstatusId("my_orders_order_id", orderId);
               //print(_setOrderstatusId);


               if(_loaded_my_orders_order_id!=null){

                 Navigator.push(
                     context,
                     MaterialPageRoute(
                         builder: (context) => MyOrderDetailsPage(

                         )));

               }

             },
```

On tap it navigate to next page but in shared preference previous id was stored an it shows the previous details.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the following steps

```
if(_loaded_my_orders_order_id!=null){
   // save the order_id to the shared prefs
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   await prefs.setInt('order_id', _loaded_my_orders_order_id);
   Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyOrderDetailsPage()));
}
```

To fetch the saved order_id from shared preferences in the app anywhere,

```
   // fetch the order_id to the shared prefs
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   int order_id=prefs.getInt('counter');
```

Then you can use it anywhere you want in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

For using `sharedpreferences` in flutter you need to follow below steps :-

- Here, data is id in your case.

**step 1: Add dependencies to pubspec.yaml file.**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: "<newest version>"
```

**step 2: Save data**

```
setID(int value) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setInt('ID', value);
}
```

**step 3: Get data**

```
getID() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //Return int
  int intValue = prefs.getInt('ID') ?? 0;
  return intValue;
}
```

[Reference](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter-251755f07127)